# Dynamic JQUERY data table width issue in IE7

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, css, datatables

We have created a dynamic JQUERY table with dynamic columns (Depending upon count value) and assigned it to DIV tag. However the thead and tbody is going outside DIV tag in IE7.

Looks like the width is automatically set dynamically by CSS, we are not able to override it.

Did anyone faced similar issues. Please help.

Comment: dataTables_scrollBody & dataTables_scrollHeader CSS we need to adjust within DIV. However its going outside DIV.

Answer (score 0):

use important keyword like this.

```
width: 100px !important;
```

Comment: No its not working. Still the header and body is outside DIV.

Answer (score 0):

Added the following lines in DataTable.css file and it worked perfectly!!

```
table.display thead th div.DataTables_sort_wrapper 
{
/*Fix for width issue*/
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    width:50px;
    overflow:hidden;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```